# Check if CQL_FILTER with WMS returns at least one feature

Tags: cql, geoserver, arcgis-js-api, wms

I am using WMS CQL_FILTER option with ArcGIS JS API. The feature works fine, but I would like to know if there is a way to test whether an expression of CQL_FILTER will return at least one feature.
Is this possible? I know a CQL_FILTER will filter depending on the expression, but does it return anything?

Thank you for your help!
Julien

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve that with WMS, that because the result is an image, the map.

If the provider also offers WFS, you can do a simple query to obtain the number of features with a determined filter.

Something like this could do the job,

```
http://your/server/wfs?request=getfeature&version=1.1&service=wfs&typename=the_namespace:the_featuretype&CQL_FILTER=the_filter&resultType=hits
```

Should get you something like this as a result,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection numberOfFeatures="X" ... />
```

Where, obviously, what you want is `numberOfFeatures`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks, I actually got it to work with OGC Features API, since ArcGIS JS API does not support WFS. Thanks anyway!